# how do multiply each layer of a tensor with another tensor?

Tags: keras

I am trying to multiply each layer of a tensor with the first layer of the tensor.

```
x1 = bert_model_1([x1_in, x2_in])
x1_begin = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0])(x1) #obtain the first layer of the bert tensor

x1_begin = Lambda(keras.layers.multiply(x11, x1_begin) for x11 in x1)([x1, x1_begin])
```

when i ran the code above, i keep getting the following errors,
<generator object build_corrector. . at 0x00000249DB234C48> is not a callable object.

the error seems to happen in the last line, how do i iterate each layer in the tensor?

Comment: the model is converted into graph, you can't not use keywords 'for', 'if' and those kinds

Comment: so what function should call if i am trying to do something like for loop?

Comment: u may need precreated x data, or use tf.while_loop, tf.cond, etc.